# function returns two random ids from the database table. asp.net core

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, random

I want to create a function returning two random ids(two questions) from the database table(one table, two Ids) and then never show these two ids **together *to this user again***.

I have all the login functionality...

I need it to have a good performance.

[image: db sample]

Comment: `RandomId rand2 = new();
int count = rand2.Random(db.Questions.OrderBy(x => x.Id).Count());
Questions question = db.Questions.Skip(count).Take(1).First();`

Comment: how many questions are talking about, 100? 10_000? 1_000_000? if you need absolute performance then you could make a collection of all the two ids combinations, and then consume them; otherwise select random id1 id2 where (id1 id2) not in history

Comment: users going to add questions i guess between 5000 -10000

Comment: then probably the db approach would be a better start, either with the two ids or with a simple hash from the 2 ids and then a fulltext search field (like {id1}_{id2))

Answer (score 0):

MSSQL

```
SELECT TOP 5 * FROM Question ORDER BY NEWID()
```

MySQL

```
SELECT * FROM Question ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 2
```

Comment: but c# function,(questions) and never show them together again for current user. I could do it with a loop, but I think it will not have good performance.